# Dynamic targetHits in Vespa yql

Tags: yql, vespa

I'm trying to create a Vespa query where I would like to set the rate limit of the targetHits. For example the query below has a constant number of 3 targetHits:

```
'yql': 'select id, title from sources * where \
        ([{"targetHits":3}]nearestNeighbor(embeddings_vector,query_embeddings_vector));'
```

Is there some way I can set this number dynamically in every call?

Also what is the difference between hits and targetHits? Does it have to do with the minimum and desired requirement?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by rate limit of targetHits but generally

- The targetHits is per content node if you run Vespa with multi-node cluster
- The targetHits is the number of hits you want to expose to the ranking profile's first phase ranking function
- hits only controls how many to return in the SERP response. It's perfectly valid to ask for targethits 500 per content node for ranking and finally just the global best 10 (according to your ranking profile)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I don't run a multi-node cluster, nor a second phase ranking function. What I currently do is use ANN to accept an embedding and return me a specified number of relevant embeddings, if that makes sense. So as I understand, hits is not required in this case?

Comment: Hits is always set - everything must work the same when you need to scale :-) The default is 10: https://docs.vespa.ai/en/reference/query-api-reference.html#hits

Comment: You always need a ranking profile even if you just want the n closest neighbors, see https://docs.vespa.ai/en/nearest-neighbor-search.html.

Comment: @Jon thanks for the clarification :). Jo, I do have a ranking profile but is solely based on the embeddings

Comment: Great @Nigat, just wanted to make sure. Some users runs into this using YQL and not specifying a ranking profile.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there some way I can set this number dynamically in every call?

You can modify the SQL you send of course, but a better way to do this is often to create a [Searcher](https://docs.vespa.ai/en/searcher-development.html) as part of your application that modifies it programmatically, e.g:

```
    public class TargetHitsSearcher extends Searcher {
    
        @Override
        public Result search(Query query, Execution execution) {
            Item root = query.getModel().getQueryTree().getRoot();
            if (root instanceof NearestNeighborItem) { // In general; search recursively
                int target = query.properties().getInteger("myTarget");
                ((NearestNeighborItem)root).setTargetNumHits(target);
            }
            return execution.search(query);
        }

    }
```